# How to verify two Images using Azure Cognitive Face API ? Need Sample Code

Tags: authentication, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition

**How to verify two Images using Azure Cognitive Face API ? Need Sample Code**

I have two images of a single person. Now I want to compare those images and check whether those images are of same person or not. From the documentation I came to know that, I have to send two faceid's along with the url. I tried that, but it is not working. May be, I am missing something. Please help me for the same & provide me some sample code for the same if possible.

Waiting for your response.

Comment: " I tried that, but it is not working. May be, I am missing something. Please help me for the same & provide me some sample code for the same if possible." < please, when having a problem, add details of your implementation, the error you faced, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the console app code below :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace FaceIdentityTest
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string persionPicPath = @"<some path>\personPic.jpg";

            String[] picsPath = { @"<some path>\pic1.jpg", @"<some path>\pic2.jpg" };

            string endpoint = @"https://<your endpoint name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
            string subscriptionKey = "<your subscription key>";



            IFaceClient faceClient = new FaceClient(
            new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey),
            new System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] { });

            faceClient.Endpoint = endpoint;

            // Create an empty PersonGroup
            Console.WriteLine("create person group");
            string personGroupId = "demogroup";
            faceClient.PersonGroup.CreateAsync(personGroupId, "demo group").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Define a person named Bill
            Console.WriteLine("create a person in group");
            var createPersonResult = faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.CreateAsync(
                // Id of the PersonGroup that the person belonged to
                personGroupId,
                // Name of the person
                "Bill"
            ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            //Add a face to Bill
            Console.WriteLine("Add a face to person");
            using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(persionPicPath))
            {
                // Detect faces in the image and add to Anna
                faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.AddFaceFromStreamAsync(
                    personGroupId, createPersonResult.PersonId, s).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            //Train person group 
            Console.WriteLine("start train person group...");
            faceClient.PersonGroup.TrainAsync(personGroupId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            //Check train status
            TrainingStatus trainingStatus = null;
            while (true)
            {
                trainingStatus = faceClient.PersonGroup.GetTrainingStatusAsync(personGroupId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                if (trainingStatus.Status != TrainingStatusType.Running)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("trainning person group...");
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }


            foreach (var pic in picsPath) {

                Console.WriteLine("start identify faces in :" + pic);

                using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(pic))
                {
                    var faces = faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(s).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    var faceIds = faces.Select(face => (Guid)face.FaceId).ToList();

                    var results = faceClient.Face.IdentifyAsync(faceIds, personGroupId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    foreach (var identifyResult in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Result of face: {0}", identifyResult.FaceId);
                        if (identifyResult.Candidates.Count == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No one identified");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Get top 1 among all candidates returned
                            var candidateId = identifyResult.Candidates[0].PersonId;
                            var person = faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.GetAsync(personGroupId, candidateId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                            Console.WriteLine("Identified as {0}", person.Name);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My pics : 
[image]

Result :

[image]

Btw, no matter which programming language you are using , just follow the steps in this demo will be able to use Face API to identify faces .

Hope it helps .

You can import Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face here in VS : 
[image]

Comment: How to get Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face ?

Comment: I tried this earlier. But it is not appearing in the list. I am using visual studio 2013 and .Net 4.5.2. Is there any problem ?

Comment: Hi @Ayan , As This page indicated : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face/2.5.0-preview.1

This package will only be available to download with SemVer 2.0.0 compatible NuGet clients, such as Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.3) and above or NuGet client 4.3.0 and above.

Maybe you can try to import it manually ...

Comment: hi @Ayan, may I know if this post is helpful for you? If so ,click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer so that it will help others who has similar issues .

Comment: Hi @Ayan , btw I am using VS 2019 and .Net Framework 4.7.2